Question about the Vector Bundle Chart Lemma
In Lee's Introduction to smooth manifolds, one may find the following lemma:

I was trying to construct a similar criterion for continuous vector bundles. Would we need condition (iii) for that? As far as I understand, it is only used to grant the compatibility of the charts that turn the bundle into a manifold. And indeed, if we define a topology on each $\pi^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ of the open cover by forcing each bijection $\Phi_\alpha$ to be a homeomorphism, and then declare a subset $W$ to be open in $E$ if and only if $W\cap\pi^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ is open in $\pi^{-1}(U_\alpha)$, don't we get a topology on $E$ that turns $\pi:E\rightarrow X$ into a continuous bundle?
However, in the answer to this question it is mentioned that the compatibility of the trivialisations is a necessary condition for the vector space structure on the fibers to be well-defined (actually, I don't really understand that sentence, because the vector space structure on the fibers is already given). What is happening here?

The vector space structure on the fibres is given, but not uniquely so: given $U_\alpha$ and $U_\beta$ such that $U_\alpha \cap U_\beta \neq \emptyset$, any fibre over a point in their intersection has two competing vector space structures, one from $\Phi_\alpha$ and one from $\Phi_\beta$. Condition 3 ensures that these are compatible with each other.

I am not sure I understand your point. In the conditions of the Vector Bundle Chart Lemma, we are given a family of vector spaces ${E_x}_{x\in X}$. Therefore, the bijections from condition (ii) do not provide the $E_x$ with a vector space structure, am I wrong? They rather "respect" it, i.e., condition (ii) is already implying that there are no different structures "competing", no? What am I missing?

Sorry, I misread the statement because I was expecting a different setup. You're right, the way this is phrased there is no ambiguity about vector space structure or linearity of the transitions: on each fibre $\Phi_\alpha \circ \Phi_\beta^{-1}$ is given by multiplying with and element of $\mathrm{GL}(k, \mathbb{R})$. Condition 3 serves to ensure that this is done smoothly. In light of this, I think your approach should work just fine (but don't take my word for it).

You might want to read through this section on vector bundles and cocycles and then try to show it is equivalent to what you're doing (basically, the way this problem is usually set up is that you're given an open cover ${U_i}{i \in I}$ of the base space and transition function $g{ij}\colon U_i \cap U_j \to \mathrm{GL}(n)$ for all $i, j$ satisfying certain properties, and then glue a vector bundle together from the $U_i \times \mathbb{R}^n$'s).
